# read from internal table with loop and no results

Tags: abap

In the below code, I read data from database table with `SELECT` into the internal table `dresult`.

Reading the first line of the internal table displays the expected result, but using the `LOOP` displays nothing.

What's the issue?

Note: I tried to remove `ENDSELECT` and it worked. Why?

```
REPORT ZTEST02.
    "Detail Informaion
TYPES : BEGIN OF details,
      d1 type arktx,        " description
      d2 type lfimg,        "quantity  
END OF details.

DATA : dresult   TYPE TABLE OF details WITH HEADER LINE,
       t_dresult TYPE details,
       sdno      TYPE vbeln.

PARAMETERS packo TYPE vbeln OBLIGATORY MATCHCODE OBJECT f4_likp.

START-OF-SELECTION.

SELECT arktx,lfimg
    INTO @dresult
    FROM lips as detail 
    LEFT JOIN marm as material
    ON detail~matnr = material~matnr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vbak
    ON detail~vgbel = vbak~vbeln
WHERE detail~vbeln = @packo.

ENDSELECT.

READ TABLE dresult into t_dresult INDEX 1.
write: t_dresult-d1,t_dresult-d2.

LOOP AT dresult INTO t_dresult.
  write: t_dresult-d1,t_dresult-d2.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: If you debug, you see that the loop at `dresult` doesn't have any problem, it's the internal table `dresult`which is empty. It's empty because of the `SELECT`. So the question should be about `SELECT`. Moreover you forgot to say that you can remove `ENDSELECT` only by inserting `TABLE` at the middle of `INTO @dresult`. Finally, that leads us to the problem of using a **header line**, and you're just one new victim of that **obsolete concept** (since 2005, and not allowed with ABAP Objects), because it's **error prone**, there were too many victims...

Comment: You argues that reading the first line works and it's displayed, but I can't reproduce (it displays only blanks, not the first line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `SELECT ... ENDSELECT` you select the data into a work area (`INTO @dresult` - which is actually the header line of the internal table with the same name). As result the internal table `dresult` does not contain any data, so the `LOOP` and the `READ TABLE` won't work.

I would declare the internal table without `HEADER LINE` and remove `ENDSELECT`:

```
DATA: dresult type STANDARD TABLE OF details,

...

SELECT ...
       INTO TABLE @dresult
```

Moreover, after `READ TABLE`, it is always good to check if an entry was found:

```
READ TABLE ...
IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
... 
ENDIF.
```